# Troubles with Internet Explorer when hosting TinyMCE on Amazon S3

Tags: internet-explorer, amazon-s3, tinymce

I am using the TinyMCE rich text editor on my site. Instead of hosting the TinyMCE files on my main site, I am using Amazon's S3 hosting to serve up the JS, image, and other files in the TinyMCE package.

With Firefox, life is good. TinyMCE get's served up nice a quick. With Internet Explorer, I get Access Denied and/or a Security Warning.

My research has me believing that this is a cross-domain scripting issue. So assuming my domain is ***www.mycompany.com***, I tried creating a CNAME like ***static.mycompany.com*** but I still get an Access Denied error message from Internet Explorer 8.0.

Is there anyway around not getting this error message using this configuration without manually relaxing the security within Internet Explorer?

Thanks for your help...

Regards,
Matthew Pomar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help: http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Cross_domain_loading

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this does not solve my problem. Even setting the domain, I still get the security warning in IE when hosting TinyMCE on Amazon S3.

Have you been able to accomplish this? Perhaps I'm missing something...